# How does Fry's grandma not recognize him in the year 1999?

Tags: futurama

After they sleep together in the past, wouldn't she recognize that this is the exact same person when he grows up?

Comment: Reminds me of Loraine and Marty in Back to the Future...

Answer (score 2):

No, she wouldn't. Children and grand-children typically looks a lot like their parents and grand-parents.

Comment: Besides, she did get to witness Fry grow up from a baby, so she probably doesn't even consider it as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

She'd have been much older and have a worse memory. Also, to my knowledge, it never specifies if she's even alive at that time. Fact is, you wouldn't remember something like that after many many years.

Comment: Actually, Fry makes mention of how his grandma always liked to make cookies for him, so she was still alive after he was born.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons: She may have already died by 1999 or she may have just though to herself 'he looks a lot like his grandfather'. It never would have occurred to her that he had traveled in time.